# Как узнать сколько раз ввели код MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая таблица, которая выше.
Мне нужно вывести на сайт - сколько раз был введен ref = code :)

Использую redbeanphp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_name WHERE code = ref
```

если надо узнать число для каждого кода отдельно

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, code FROM table_name WHERE code = ref GROUP BY code
```